# Use sed to change first occurrence after match

Tags: bash, sed

I have worked out the syntax to get `sed` to replace after the match, but it replaces all instances following the match. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I know it's something minor but I can't seem to get it to take.

```
sed -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/" FILE1 > FILE2
```

I have also tried

```
sed -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/1" FILE1 > FILE2
```

Here is the full line with the sed commands and the data it is to change.

```
sed -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/" -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$NEW_VER/$VER/" -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$EVEN_LENGTH/$OLD_EVEN_LENGTH/" -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$ODD_LENGTH/$OLD_ODD_LENGTH/" -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$START_DIGIT/$OLD_START_DIGIT/" -e "0,/\#NOTE/!  s/$STRING/$OLD_STRING/ FILE1 > FILE2"
```

Basically it should find the string "#NOTE" and replace only the first instance following the match.

```
    #CHANGE THESE EVERY VERSION
#NOTE: Don't forget to add the needed variables to the version arguments. 
   DEFAULT_VERSION = REPVVER
   EVEN_LENGTH = REPELENGTH 
   ODD_LENGTH = REPOLENGTH  
   CURR_VERSION = "REPVVER"
   START_DIGIT = REPSTARTDIGIT
###########################################
```

for example it should find the string "#NOTE" and replace the "REPVVER" string with a new value. But it will replace not only that one but all following.

Comment: Please show sample data (3-10 lines of input, say), and the sample output.  Showing suitable values for `NEW_VVER` and `CURRENT_VER` might help.  Was the double-V intentional?  It's no problem if it is; it's a major problem if it wasn't.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Yes the double V is intended 

Here is what it should be changing 
`#NOTE: Don't forget to add the needed variables to the version arguments. 
   DEFAULT_VERSION = REPVVER`

It should only be changing that instance of REPVVER but instead it will change all instances of REPVVER

Comment: Note that `0` as the lower bound of an address range is a GNU extension.

Comment: So the string to replace appears on the same line as `#NOTE`, or on the next line?

Comment: Sorry I did an edit on the main question to clerify some. It's on the following line.

Comment: So, given the update I made to the input, is the hypothesized desired output correct?  Also, is using `awk` an option or does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: Yes awk is an option, I was just more comfortable with sed.

Comment: Can the `#NOTE` line appear more than once in the file?  Or is it a singleton entry?

Comment: It only appears once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed -e '/#NOTE/!b' -e ':a' -e "s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/;t trail" -e 'n;ba' -e ':trail' -e 'n;btrail' FILE1 > FILE2
```

- posix compliant and oneliner (replace all `' -e '` with a new line for a multiline script (also `"` and replace surrounding `'`by `"` for variable interpretation )
- change the first occurence of `NEW_VVER` after `#NOTE` but not on same line (assumming # note is a comment line). Linne could be 50th after `#NOTE`
- Assuming content of `NEW_VVER` and `CURRENT_VER` are regex compliant (escaping meta char like `&`)

Comment: Interesting one, could you explain a bit more the rest of the sections?

Comment: I can't make it work on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively rough way to do it:

```
sed -e "/\#NOTE/,/./  s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/" FILE1 > FILE2
```

That limits the substitution to the line containing `#NOTE` and the next line.  It will be performed at most once in each line.

This approach assumes that the substitution will change nothing on the `#NOTE` line.  That assumption holds for your example data, but you'll have to decide whether it is acceptable in general.

**Update:**

If the line in which to perform the substitution does not immediately follow the `#NOTE` line, *and if you can depend on the value of `$NEW_VVER` to not contain any regex metacharacters*, then you can do it with this variation on the above:

```
sed -e "/\#NOTE/,/$NEW_VVER/  s/$NEW_VVER/$CURRENT_VER/" FILE1 > FILE2
```

In that case, the range of lines to which the substitution applies starts with one matching `/\#NOTE/`, and ends with the next one matching `/$NEW_VVER/`.  As above, this assumes that the substitution will change nothing in the `/\#NOTE/` line.

Comment: This unfortunately wouldn't work as I have multiple changes to make and they are not all on the line directly below the match.

Comment: I tried it and it does (safely) replace the first occurrence after `#NOTE` on the *same line* (not sure that's an issue?); Also works on older versions of GNU which is always a bonus.

Comment: @l'L'l, yes, the substitution will be performed on the `#NOTE` line, as I already mentioned.  The OP will have to decide whether that's a problem.

Comment: @leigon, Consider the alternative I added.  It is slightly more restricted, in that the string to replace must not contain regex metacharacetrs, but that is not a problem for your example data.

Comment: Can you break down how this works? Its almost there just seeing some issues where random variables are going to the wrong spots.

Comment: An address range of the form `/.../,/.../` says that the associated command (`s/.../.../` in this case) should be performed on each line in each range of lines starting with one matched by the first regex and ending with the next subsequent line matching the second regex.  Since here the second regex is the same as the one for which you want to perform the substitution, the first line in such a range on which that substitution can be performed will be the last one in the range, therefore the substitution will be performed only once (or twice if the `#NOTES` line also matches the pattern).