# Replacing first occurrence line after first matched line

Tags: sed

Let's assume the following XML file:

```
    some text
    <addresses>
      <something/>
    </addresses>
    some more text
    <addresses xmlns="namespace">
      <could be anything/>
    </addresses>
    some other text
    <addresses>
      <something else/>
    </addresses>
    ...
```

I need to replace the first `</addresses>` following the first `<addresses xmlns="namespace">` by `</namespace:addresses>` so that the file becomes:

```
    some text
    <addresses>
      <something/>
    </addresses>
    some more text
    <addresses xmlns="namespace">
      <could be anything/>
    </namespace:addresses>
    some other text
    <addresses>
      <something else/>
    </addresses>
    ...
```

I am aware of [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382922/use-sed-to-change-first-occurrence-after-match), but none of the following solution changes anything:

```
sed -e '/<addresses xmlns="namespace">/!b' -e ':a' -e "s/<\/namespace:addresses>/<\/addresses>/;t trail" -e 'n;ba' -e ':trail' -e 'n;btrail' file.xml
sed -e "/<addresses xmlns=\"namespace\">/,/./  s/<\/namespace:addresses>/<\/addresses>/" file.xml
sed -e "/<addresses xmlns=\"namespace\">/,/<\/namespace:addresses>/  s/<\/namespace:addresses>/<\/addresses>/" file.xml
```

For instance:

```
sed -e "/<addresses xmlns=\"namespace\">/,/./  s/<\/namespace:addresses>/<\/addresses>/" file.xml
    some text
    <addresses>
      <something/>
    </addresses>
    some more text
    <addresses xmlns="namespace">
      <could be anything/>
    </addresses>
    some other text
    <addresses>
      <something else/>
    </addresses>
    ...
```

Maybe this issue is linked to the sed I'm using: 4.7-1ubuntu1 on impish/21.10 or even 4.8-1.

Any suggestion?
I'm open to any other tool (perl/awk), the simpler, the better.

Comment: Using `sed` to process XML is very brittle and error-prone. Probably look at an XML-aware tool like `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: The contents of the files can be anything so the xpath changes all the time and I have no access to their xslt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier with `perl` than with `sed`:

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's~<(addresses)\s+xmlns="namespace">[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*\K</\1>~</namespace:$1>~' file
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RNRzWK). *Details*:

- `<(addresses)\s+xmlns="namespace">[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*\K</\1>` - the regex pattern matching

  - `<` - a `<` char
  - `(addresses)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `addresses`
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `xmlns="namespace">` - a fixed string
  - `[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*` - a much faster alternative to `(?s:.)*?` - basically, matches any text up to a `</addresses>` string
  - `\K` - match reset operator that omits all text matched so far from the current match memory buffer
  - `</\1>` - (this is what is finally consumed and will be replaced): `</` + Group 1 value (so  as not to repeat `addresses`) + `>`
- `</namespace:$1>` - the replacement is `</namespace:` + Group 1 value + `>`.

It replaces the first occurrence because the `-0777` slurps the file into a single multiline text and there is no `g` flag.

Note the difference between `\1` backreference syntax inside the pattern and `$1` replacement backreference in the replacement pattern in `perl` command.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/RNRzWK):

```sh
s='    some text
    <addresses>
      <something/>
    </addresses>
    some more text
    <addresses xmlns="namespace">
      <could be anything/>
    </addresses>
    some other text
    <addresses>
      <something else/>
    </addresses>
    ...'
perl -0777 -pe 's~<(addresses)\s+xmlns="namespace">[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*\K</\1>~</namespace:$1>~' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
 some text
    <addresses>
      <something/>
    </addresses>
    some more text
    <addresses xmlns="namespace">
      <could be anything/>
    </namespace:addresses>
    some other text
    <addresses>
      <something else/>
    </addresses>
    ...
```

Comment: If I try to replace addresses and namespace by variables, I have to replace the single quotes by double quotes and escape internal double-quotes. Then I get: !/\1: event not found. What is happening?

Comment: @jean-christophemanciot `!` should only be used inside single quotes to avoid issues. Use it like `perl -0777 -pe 's~<('"$ad"')\s+xmlns="'"$nm"'">[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*\K</\1>~</'"$nm"':$1>~'`, see [the online demo](https://ideone.com/IdGKVM). Or even like `perl -0777 -pe 's~<('"$ad"')\s+xmlns="('"$nm"')">[^<]*(?:<(?!/\1>)[^<]*)*\K</\1>~</$2:$1>~'` ([demo](https://ideone.com/Kfqd2I)).